# How to interfere the invisible items of a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am working on RecyclerView with a large number of data horizontally as seen in the image. I need to place an appropriate image on each button however only visible items of RecyclerView are gonna be affected and invisible items are not.

> My RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCarPart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true" />
```

> My adapter

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(dataBinding.rvCarPart.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        dataBinding.rvCarPart.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        dataBinding.rvCarPart.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mCategories = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.PARCELABLE_EXTRA_KEY);

        if (mCategories == null) return;

        mCurrentStatusAdapter.setData(mCategories);
        dataBinding.rvCarPart.setAdapter(mCurrentStatusAdapter);
```

> Relative adapter code in activity - I use EventBus here and each
>   fragment sends a signal to my activity in order to update the
>   imageview.

```
@Subscribe
    @AllowConcurrentEvents
    public void onEvent(ButtonEvent buttonEvent) {
        if (buttonEvent.isNull()) {
            mCurrentStatusAdapter.changeVisibilityOfSelectorAt(buttonEvent.getColumnPosition(), R.drawable.ic_undone);
        } else {
            mCurrentStatusAdapter.changeVisibilityOfSelectorAt(buttonEvent.getColumnPosition(), R.drawable.ic_done);
        }
    }
```

> Relative method inside CurrentStatusAdapter

```
public void changeVisibilityOfSelectorAt(int position, @DrawableRes int drawable) {
        mImageViews.get(position).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImageViews.get(position).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mViews.get(position).getContext(), drawable));
    }
```

[image]

**Note:** Sorry, Imgur is blocked in Turkey and I couldn't make it with VPN, either, so that I had to upload from my PC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you decide to make an item of a recyclerview invisible? The same logic should be applied here too... if I got the question :)

Comment: Can you please post your adapter code?

Comment: Thanks @Shivam I don't decide, just some items are out of the screen and so that they are invisible at first run.

Comment: Thanks @MayurGajra I updated the question.

Comment: I actually asked for `mCurrentStatusAdapter`  code where you are putting the image setting logic.

Comment: Thanks @MayurGajra I updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I guess there is some misunderstanding,i said whole adapter file code would be needed to understand the issue so please update it.

Comment: Hi @MayurGajra as it might be too long to paste here, I shared it by a pastebin style website. Please have a look at it here. http://pasted.co/e94f95ab

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and found that you are storing views in an `SparseArray` and then you are trying to update it on button event.Well that would't work,it would give you problem that you said all the visible views will be affected and invisible items wouldn't be affected because those invisible items are actually recycled or you could say they do not exist anymore so any changes to those wouldn't work.

The most correct way to do this will be to store value in model and update views from it when they become visible.

I didn't have many of your classes such as `Categories`,`BaseViewHolder` etc. but still i am trying to put an example below to fit your case:

Let us consider that i have a model `Categories` and i want to display an `ic_done` if the category is selected and `ic_undone` if the category is unselcted so what i would do is:

In `MyActivity` class:

```
public void onEvent(ButtonEvent buttonEvent) {
        if (buttonEvent.isNull()) {
            Categories categories = list.get(buttonEvent.getColumnPosition());
            categories.setSelected(false);
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
        } else {
            Categories categories= list.get(buttonEvent.getColumnPosition());
            categories.setSelected(true);
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
    }
```

In `CurrentStatusAdapter` class.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CurrentPartViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
        Categories categories = data.get(position);

        if (categories.isSelected()){
            holder.getImageView().setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_done);
        }else {
            holder.getImageView().setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_undone);
        }

    }
```

I hope it does cover your case,if not then let me know in comments.

Comment: Thanks, Mayur! I gave it a try but didn't work. So I use ViewPager and its size varies the size of a model. So there might be 20 fragments even. So this could be related to ViewPager? What do you think?

Comment: @nuhkoca Sorry for that,But that should have worked,It has nothing to do with ViewPager,I think some logic is missing in between,If you don't mind sharing your code through github link(update in your question) it might be helpful to understand the flow else i am unclear on your issue.